# Airflow scheduler stops running when using requests library in task

Tags: python-requests, airflow, webserver

my airflow scheduler stops running on tasks that utilize the requests library.
Other tasks in my dag will run but anytime a task with a request method in it tries to ru, Airflow shows the following message:

"The scheduler does not appear to be running. Last heartbeat was received 23 minutes ago.

The DAGs list may not update, and new tasks will not be scheduled."

Also, the task with the request doesn't fail, it just gets stuck on "running" and never changes.

Any ideas on what might be going on with my code or environment?

Here is one of my DAG files below that experiences the issue.

IMPORTANT: This doesn't occur on my teammates build of Airflow just mine. He is running the same code.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import jwt
import requests
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.models import Variable
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator

# Define the DAG
dag_args = {
    'owner': 'John.Smith',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'end_date': None,
    'email': ['jsmith@applejohn.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 3,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=3)
}

dag = DAG(
    'create_jwt_dag_v5',
    default_args=dag_args,
    description='DAG task for authenticating to Salesforce API',
    schedule_interval='@daily',
    start_date=datetime(2023, 6, 28),
    catchup=False,
    access_control={
        "TYX-ENG-LSV-TUS-SEV": {"can_read", "can_edit"},
    },
)


def create_jwt():
    # Define the payload for the JWT
    payload = {
        'iss': 'M4dfd484jrsafd89iddveaavnbd.thevesv.avasdfdfv334r44w2eav.6790n34tz',
        'aud': 'https://test.salesforce.com',
        'sub': 'servicenow_integration@applejohn.com',
        'exp': datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(days=1)  # Expiration time
    }

    secret_key = Variable.get("your-secret-key")
    print("Key:", secret_key)

    # Load the private key
    private_key = secret_key.encode('utf-8')

    # Generate the JWT
    jwt_token = jwt.encode(payload, private_key, algorithm='RS256')

    # Print or do something with the generated JWT
    print("Generated JWT:", jwt_token)

    return jwt_token


def call_salesforce(jwt_token):
    salesforce_endpoint = 'https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token'
    salesforce_url_params = {
        'grant_type': 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer',
        'assertion': jwt_token
    }

    response = requests.post(salesforce_endpoint, params=salesforce_url_params, verify=False)
    print(response.content)


# Define the JWT task
create_jwt_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='create_jwt',
    python_callable=create_jwt,
    dag=dag
)

# Define the Salesforce task
call_salesforce_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='call_salesforce',
    python_callable=call_salesforce,
    op_kwargs={'jwt_token': create_jwt_task.output},
    dag=dag
)

# Set the task dependencies
create_jwt_task >> call_salesforce_task
```

I tried killing and restarting my web server and scheduler.